# gethostbyname() Showing wierd results while domain validation

Tags: php, gethostbyname

This is the code iam using for validating the domain name using gethostbyname().

This is working fine until i use it on localhost.

As soon as i upload it on my server,gethostbyname() started returning ip address of the unknown domain name as well.

```
$url=$_GET['d'];
function getHost($Address) { 
           $parseUrl = parse_url(trim($Address)); 
           return trim($parseUrl['host'] ? $parseUrl['host'] : array_shift(explode('/', $parseUrl['path'], 2))); 
        }

  $get=getHost($url);
  $domain = str_ireplace('www.', '', $get);

 if(filter_var(gethostbyname($domain), FILTER_VALIDATE_IP))
{
echo gethostbyname($domain);
echo $domain;
}
else
{
echo gethostbyname($domain);
   echo "Not Valid";
}
```

My test cases are :-

1)www- it return 184.173.134.234

2)google.coma- it returns 67.215.65.132

3)google.comaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa - it returns 67.215.65.132

One more interesting thing happening is that for these same domain name when i run them on my localhost .this same function returns Not valid.

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer and research by Ben D...

```
# Get the URL from the GET Parameters
$url = $_GET['d'];

# Derive the HTTP Host
$hostname = parse_url( $url , PHP_URL_HOST );
# Strip the "WWW." from the hostname if present
$hostname = preg_replace( '/^www\./i' , '' , $hostname );

# Look for the IP Address
$ip_address = gethostbyname( $hostname );

if( filter_var( $hostname , FILTER_VALIDATE_IP ) ){
  echo 'Hostname is an IP Address already';
  echo $hostname;
}elseif( $ip_address==$hostname || $ip_address=='67.215.65.132' ){
  echo 'Domain Not Found';
}elseif( filter_var( $ip_address , FILTER_VALIDATE_IP ) ){
  echo $ip_address;
  echo $hostname;
}else{
  echo 'Invalid IP Address Returned';
  echo $ip_address;
  echo $hostname;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucanos for your help..it worked and i understand the concept clearly now... Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 1):

67.215.65.132 is a "Not Available" redirect used, I believe, by OpenDNS:

```
IP + HOSTNAME INFORMATION
IP: 67.215.66.132 Hostname:hit-servfail.opendns.com
Active Servers: http/80 https/443 LOCATION
```

Your DNS service is trying to look up an invalid domain, finds nothing, so it attempts to redirect you to a default "not available" IP address... Try switching your DNS services if this is a self-hosted project.

Comment: thanks for the answer but mine is shared server. so is there any way around.

Comment: @rsdev8: Try and assume that a returned value of "67.215.65.132" is the same as the `gethostbyname()` function failing.

Comment: Thanks @Ben D ..for you help..appreciate it :)